# Grouping JSON elements together based upon unifying object [Python]

Tags: python, json

Based upon the following JSON

```
 "Records":   [
        {
      "Action_Id": "5542.3478.137599",
      "SKU": "DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
      "SubId1": "1011l4dIyBtf",

    },
        {
      "Action_Id": "5542.3477.118504",
      "SKU": "DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
      "SubId1": "1101l4dI2VPX",

    },
        {
      "Action_Id": "5542.3477.118504",
      "SKU": "PARCMEPGR15_C6",
      "SubId1": "1101l4dI2VPX",

    },
        {
      "Action_Id": "5542.3477.117975",
      "SKU": "DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
      "SubId1": "1101l4dI2Hwz",
    },
        {
      "Action_Id": "5542.3477.117852",
      "SKU": "DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
      "SubId1": "1101l4dI2EZK",

    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to group elements based upon `Action_Id`. So using the above data, the output would be

```
{"Records": [
    {
        "Action_Id:":"5542.3477.118504",
            "Items":
                [
                    {
                        "SKU":"DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
                        "SubId1":"1101l4dI2VPX"
                    },
                    {
                        "SKU":"PARCMEPGR15_C6",
                        "SubId1":"1101l4dI2VPX"
                    }
                ],
    },
    {
        "Action_Id":"5542.3478.137599",
            "Items":
                [
                    {
                        "SKU":"DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
                        "SubID1":"1011l4dIyBtf"
                    }
                ],
    },
    {
        "Action_Id":"5542.3477.117975",
            "Items":
                [
                    {
                        "SKU":"DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
                        "SubID1":"1101l4dI2Hwz"
                    }
                ],
    },
    {
        "Action_Id":"5542.3477.117852",
            "Items":
                [
                    {
                        "SKU":"DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
                        "SubID1":"1101l4dI2EZK"
                    }
                ],
    }

]
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem, but I'm not seeing anything python code. JSON also isn't really important here. It's a Python dictionary, so treat it as one

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
import collections,itertools
a_dict = { "Records":   [
        {
      "Action_Id": "5542.3478.137599",
      "SKU": "DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
      "SubId1": "1011l4dIyBtf",

    },
        {
      "Action_Id": "5542.3477.118504",
      "SKU": "DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
      "SubId1": "1101l4dI2VPX",

    },
        {
      "Action_Id": "5542.3477.118504",
      "SKU": "PARCMEPGR15_C6",
      "SubId1": "1101l4dI2VPX",

    },
        {
      "Action_Id": "5542.3477.117975",
      "SKU": "DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
      "SubId1": "1101l4dI2Hwz",
    },
        {
      "Action_Id": "5542.3477.117852",
      "SKU": "DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
      "SubId1": "1101l4dI2EZK",

    }
  ]
}
temp_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, group in itertools.groupby(a_dict['Records'], lambda item: item["Action_Id"]): #group by Action_Id
    for e in group:        
        del e['Action_Id'] #remove key,value for key = Action_Id
        temp_dict[key].append(e) 

result_list=  [{'Action_Id':key, 'Items': value} for key,value in temp_dict.items()]
result_dict = {"Records":result_list}
result_dict
```

`result_dict` will be:

```
{'Records': [{'Action_Id': '5542.3478.137599',
   'Items': [{'SKU': 'DSOLSSREDGUM_V', 'SubId1': '1011l4dIyBtf'}]},
  {'Action_Id': '5542.3477.117975',
   'Items': [{'SKU': 'DSOLSSREDGUM_V', 'SubId1': '1101l4dI2Hwz'}]},
  {'Action_Id': '5542.3477.118504',
   'Items': [{'SKU': 'DSOLSSREDGUM_V', 'SubId1': '1101l4dI2VPX'},
    {'SKU': 'PARCMEPGR15_C6', 'SubId1': '1101l4dI2VPX'}]},
  {'Action_Id': '5542.3477.117852',
   'Items': [{'SKU': 'DSOLSSREDGUM_V', 'SubId1': '1101l4dI2EZK'}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach will work:

```
# create new dict with necessary keys
new_json = {'Records':[{'Action_Id':v} for v in set([i['Action_Id'] for i in original_json['Records']])]}

# iterate over the previous dict to find items values
# while filtering out Action_Id values, which are now in the keys
for i in new_json['Records']:
    i['items'] = [{k:v for k, v in j.iteritems() if k != 'Action_Id'} for j in original_json['Records'] if i['Action_Id'] == j['Action_Id']]

# convert to json string
new_json = json.dumps(new_json)
```

Result:

```
'{
    "Records": [{
        "items": [{
            "SKU": "DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
            "SubId1": "1011l4dIyBtf"
        }],
        "Action_Id": "5542.3478.137599"
    }, {
        "items": [{
            "SKU": "DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
            "SubId1": "1101l4dI2Hwz"
        }],
        "Action_Id": "5542.3477.117975"
    }, {
        "items": [{
            "SKU": "DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
            "SubId1": "1101l4dI2VPX"
        }, {
            "SKU": "PARCMEPGR15_C6",
            "SubId1": "1101l4dI2VPX"
        }],
        "Action_Id": "5542.3477.118504"
    }, {
        "items": [{
            "SKU": "DSOLSSREDGUM_V",
            "SubId1": "1101l4dI2EZK"
        }],
        "Action_Id": "5542.3477.117852"
    }]
}'
```